# Java function for 2 a bit different objects

Tags: java

I have 2 entity classes a bit different from each other, but mostly similar,
and I have 2 functions which use them.
`StudentData` and `PassData` both have methods like `getDatatype()` and `getPassIndLinkId()`.

What can I do to avoid writing similar code 2 times?

```
private StudentData getStudentDataEqual(PassIndLinkReq passIndLinkReq, List<StudentData> dataList, Long val){        
    for (StudentData data:dataList) {
       if (data.getPassIndLinkId().intValue()==passIndLinkReq.getId().intValue()){
            switch (passIndLinkReq.getDatatype().intValue()) {
              case 0:  
              case 1: 
                 return data;
              case 7: 
                 if (data.getClassItemTreeId().equals(val)){
                     return data;
                 }
                 break;
              ...
            }
        }        
    }                        
    return new StudentData();
}   
// and this
private PassData getStudentDataEqual(PassIndLinkReq passIndLinkReq, List<PassData> dataList, Long val){        
    for (PassData data:dataList){
       if (data.getPassIndLinkId().intValue()==passIndLinkReq.getId().intValue()) {
           switch (passIndLinkReq.getDatatype().intValue()) {
             case 0:  
             case 1: 
               return data;
             case 7: 
               if (data.getClassItemTreeId().equals(val)){
                   return data;
               }
               break;
             ...
           }
        }        
    }                        
    return new PassData();
}
```

Comment: Are StudentData and PassData related?  Is one a subclass of another?

Comment: Thought about using interfaces?

Comment: Using interface does not prevent to write the code twice, interfaces are used when there are different ways to achieve the same effect. If the code is shared use a common parent class.

Comment: @fustaki Using an interface in this case would clearly avoid needing to write the code twice.

Comment: I think a problem could be that he is creating a new instance of the return type. That would not be possible with an interface. He could also use a super class and cast it afterwards, which is a bit dirty, but should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a new super class (instead of an Interface, because you are returning a new instance) which both of your classes inherit:

```
public class Data { ... }

public class StudentData extends Data { ... }

public class PassData extends Data { ... }
```

Which wouldn't be the most clean variant, but should work fine.

```
private Data getStudentDataEqual(PassIndLinkReq passIndLinkReq, List<Data> dataList, Long val){        
    for (T data:dataList){
        if (data.getPassIndLinkId().intValue()==passIndLinkReq.getId().intValue()) {
            switch (passIndLinkReq.getDatatype().intValue()) {
                case 0:  
                case 1: 
                    return data;
                case 7: 
                    if (data.getClassItemTreeId().equals(val)){
                        return data;
                    }
                    break;
                ...
                }
            }        
        }                        
    return new Data();
}
```

But with this solution, you would need to cast the return value afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned already before it would help to know whether `StudentData` and `PassData` implement some common interface or have a common base class.

Without knowing anything about the two objects, you can still do something like the following:

```
private <T> T getStudentDataEqual(PassIndLinkReq passIndLinkReq, List<T> dataList, Long val,
                                  ToIntFunction<? super T> passIndLinkIdAccessor,
                                  Function<? super T, ?> classItemTreeIdAccessor,
                                  Supplier<? extends T> factory) {
    for (T data:dataList) {
        if (passIndLinkIdAccessor.applyAsInt(data)==passIndLinkReq.getId().intValue()){
            switch (passIndLinkReq.getDatatype().intValue()) {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                    return data;
                case 7:
                    if (classItemTreeIdAccessor.apply(data).equals(val)){
                        return data;
                    }
                    break;
                //...
            }
        }
    }
    return factory.get();
}


private StudentData getStudentDataEqual(PassIndLinkReq passIndLinkReq, List<StudentData> dataList, Long val){
    return getStudentDataEqual(passIndLinkReq, dataList, val,
            data -> data.getPassIndLinkId().intValue(),
            data -> data.getClassItemTreeId(), StudentData::new);
}
private PassData getPassDataEqual(PassIndLinkReq passIndLinkReq, List<PassData> dataList, Long val) {
    return getStudentDataEqual(passIndLinkReq, dataList, val,
            data -> data.getPassIndLinkId().intValue(),
            data -> data.getClassItemTreeId(), PassData::new);
}
```

Comment: Is this for java 8?

Comment: Yes it uses Lambda Expressions hence Java 8 or newer

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you could try: If StudentData and PassData are unrelated, you could create a superclass that they can both inherit from, and implement the methods required for your function in this class.  (If they are related, you can probably just use the function using the superclass).

The other option is to create an interface that has the methods required for your function, and implement this interface in both StudentData and PassData classes.

Answer (score 0):

StudentData and PassData should both be subclasses of a more general abstract class 'GeneralData' or similar, which has the appropriate getPassIndLinkId() and getClassItemTreeId() methods - in fact all common methods.

Then you can use a single method utilizing this GeneralData class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like getStudentDataEqual() is some kind of data retrieval from a list, so you could - as a third option to those already given in the other answers - create a generic container class that can store and retrieve instances of those two and possible other classes as well.

In that case, getStudentDataEqual() would just use the container to do the retrieval, so those methods would be very short in both classes.